# How can I improve this table, and subsequently the performance of the queries I execute on it?

Tags: mysql, index, normalization

I have inherited this table of POS transaction level data. In my opinion it is terrible. There are 3.5 million rows, which span ~4 years, with a distribution of anywhere between 1 result and 100k results for things like `sku`, `brand`, `nationality` and `destination`.

There is no primary key, and I am struggling to figure how I can implement one.

here is the `CREATE TABLE`

```
CREATE TABLE `transaction_data` (
  `txn_id` varchar(32) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nationality_id` int(3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `transaction date` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `YrQtr` varchar(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Yr` int(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mth` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dy` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `destination` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sku` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sales` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `units` int(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `txnid` (`txn_id`),
  KEY `cov` (`sku`,`nationality_id`,`Yr`,`YrQtr`),
  KEY `period` (`Yr`,`YrQtr`,`mth`),
  KEY `natperiod` (`nationality_id`,`Yr`,`YrQtr`),
  KEY `desperiod` (`destination`,`Yr`,`YrQtr`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Here are 4 example rows of data:

**txn_id** - is a non unique weird concatenate of field values, which represent which **basket** the **sku** was purchased in.

In some **transactions**, the **sku** is not unique, as POS reductions are recorded by another row with the same `txn_id` and `sku` but with negative values in sales and units to reflect those.

```
    INSERT INTO `2_sar`.`transaction_data`
(`txn_id`,
`nationality_id`,
`transaction date`,
`YrQtr`,
`Yr`,
`mth`,
`dy`,
`destination`,
`sku`,
`sales`,
`units`)
VALUES
('1_20120113_EZY 1832_3_08:58:00', '143', '20120113', '2012Q1', '2012', '1', '13', 'United Kingdom - Manchstr UK', '30312', '52.00', '1'
), ('1_20120121_OR  367_1_11:21:00', '143', '20120121', '2012Q1', '2012', '1', '21', 'Neth Antills - Curacao', '710028', '3.95', '1'
), ('1_20120203_PC  672_2_13:07:00', '200', '20120203', '2012Q1', '2012', '2', '3', 'Turkey - Istanbul', '1840', '27.95', '1'
), ('1_20120203_PC  672_2_13:07:00', '200', '20120203', '2012Q1', '2012', '2', '3', 'Turkey - Istanbul', '2156', '12.95', '1'
);
;
```

Here is a query which I run on the data.

This query finds the top 10 brands that are purchased with `<Brand>` (not including `<brand>`) ordered by total number of transactions.

This query took 11.344 seconds to run directly from mysql workbench. The server is a t2.micro AWS RDS Instance, and I usually run the queries from a separate EC2 web server. which I believe is (1GHz, 1GB).

The wildcards in this query represent `<select>` filters on the PHP page which the query is run from. They may or may not be selected.

```
SELECT  `products`.`brand`, COUNT(DISTINCT transaction_data.txn_id) AS numOrders
    FROM  `products`
    INNER JOIN  `transaction_data` ON `transaction_data`.sku=`products`.sku
    INNER JOIN  `nationalities` ON `transaction_data`.`nationality_id` =
                                      `nationalities`.`nationality_id`
    INNER JOIN  
      ( SELECT  DISTINCT `transaction_data`.`txn_id`
            FROM  `transaction_data`
            INNER JOIN  `products` USING (sku)
            INNER JOIN  `nationalities` USING (nationality_id)
            WHERE  brand = <Brand>
      ) AS tmp_txns ON tmp_txns.txn_id=`transaction_data`.txn_id
    WHERE  brand <> <Brand>
      AND  nationality LIKE '%'
      AND  Yr = '2014'
      AND  YrQtr LIKE '%'
    GROUP BY  brand
    ORDER BY  numOrders DESC, brand ASC
    LIMIT  10
```

And the explain:

```
+----+-------------+------------------+--------+----------------------------+----------+---------+---------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type |      table       |  type  |       possible_keys        |   key    | key_len |                  ref                  |  rows   |                    Extra                     |
+----+-------------+------------------+--------+----------------------------+----------+---------+---------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2>       | ALL    |                            |          |         |                                       | 1295294 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | transaction_data | ref    | txnid,cov,period,natperiod | txnid    |      99 | tmp_txns.txn_id                       |       1 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | nationalities    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,natv               | PRIMARY  |       4 | 2_sar.transaction_data.nationality_id |       1 | Using where                                  |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | products         | ref    | skubrand                   | skubrand |       5 | 2_sar.transaction_data.sku            |       1 | Using where; Using index                     |
|  2 | DERIVED     | products         | index  | skubrand                   | skubrand |     128 |                                       |    2669 | Using where; Using index; Using temporary    |
|  2 | DERIVED     | transaction_data | ref    | txnid,cov,natperiod        | cov      |       5 | 2_sar.products.sku                    |     647 | Using index condition                        |
|  2 | DERIVED     | nationalities    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,natv               | PRIMARY  |       4 | 2_sar.transaction_data.nationality_id |       1 | Using index                                  |
+----+-------------+------------------+--------+----------------------------+----------+---------+---------------------------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------+
```

Here are create table statements for the reference tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `nationalities` (
  `nationality_id` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `nationality` varchar(14) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`nationality_id`),
  KEY `natv` (`nationality_id`,`nationality`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `products` (
  `sku` int(6) DEFAULT NULL,
  `category` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `subcategory` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `brand` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `product name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pack size` decimal(8,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rk_group` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `rk_category` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `skubrand` (`sku`,`brand`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**My Thoughts So Far**

The `txn_id` is almost guaranteed to bring poor performance, not only due to the fact it's non-unique, but also because it's a string rather than an int. But I need some sort of non-unique identifier for the basket.

I think my `indexes` are okay. All my queries use them, and obviously some `indexes` are specific to certain queries where a single composite `index` won't serve the different `where` clauses in queries.

EDIT: This question has been elaborated on [HERE](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/129693/how-can-i-further-improve-my-table-and-queries)

Comment: Apparently a dup of http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?24,642629,642629#msg-642629

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- InnoDB tables really need an explicit `PRIMARY KEY`.  If you don't have a 'natural' key, add an `AUTO_INCREMENT`.
- `INT(3)` and `INT(99)` mean the same thing -- a 4-byte binary number.  Consider changing to `TINYINT UNSIGNED`, which takes 1 byte and stores 0..255.  Or SMALLINT, etc.  (Smaller -> more cacheable -> less I/O -> faster.)
- The subquery needs an index *starting* with `brand`.  Either flip `(sku, brand)` or add `INDEX(brand)`.  That will be the biggest performance boost.
- In `nationalities`, there is no need for the secondary key.  The data and the `PRIMARY KEY` are clustered together, effectively making it like that key.  If you ever need to look up by `nationality` to find the id, you need to add `UNIQUE(nationality)`
- Every column but one is `NULLable` -- are they really optional?  Make them `NOT NULL` where appropriate.
- Splitting a date into its component parts wastes space and *usually* provides no performance.  The parts can be extracted during the queries.
- I suspect `transaction_date` is a date; if so, use the `DATE` datatype so that functions are easy to apply to it.
- After the above date changes, `AND  Yr = '2014'` becomes `AND transaction_date >= '2014-01-01' AND transaction_date < '2014-01-01' + INTERVAL 1 YEAR`.  Do something similar for quarters, etc.:  `+ INTERVAL 3 MONTH`.
- `YrQtr LIKE '%'` has terrible performance characteristics since YrQtr is `INT`.  (The above changes obviate the need for fixing it.)
- When something is not relevant (eg `AND  nationality LIKE '%'`) have the app not include it in the query.

Is the transaction data "write-once"?  That is, once written, do you delete or update the rows or insert more "old" rows?  If not, the building and maintaining [Summary tables](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) will further speed up the queries, perhaps 10-fold.

Make those changes, then come back for more advice.  (Start a new Question; this one would become too messy to follow with new schema, queries, etc.)

Comment: Running your DB on a micro instance over at AWS is not advisable. Any database with more than a few thousand rows is going to benefit from going to at least a small. MySQL is a huge memory hog and the memory allocated on a micro instance is of little to no benefit. Additionally running your query from another server doesn't benefit the server at all. Your database still does all the work. Except now the db server has to send all of it's output to your other server.

Comment: @Mark has a point.  In 1GB of RAM, you would need to set `innodb_buffer_pool_size really low, perhaps under 60M.  That means that the data is _much_ bigger than can be cached, so a table scan (which _this_ query currently is) will be I/O-bound, hence slow.  Shoot for at least 4GB of RAM, with the buffer_pool set to 1500M.

Comment: If you cannot upgrade, then my comments become even more important.  Changing an `INT` to a `TINYINT` saves about 10MB.  Even more if it is in an index.  And getting rid of the various date fields and their indexes will save lots more.  Etc.

Comment: I've always read that innodb_buffer_pool_size is best set at 75% of ram? or is that just the limit? I can't upgrade right now unfortunately but am aware it's a key consideration. unfortunately the decision isn't in my hands. I have kept the db separate for the web server because given the type of application, if it becomes popular among clients as intended  then it will take some hammer and as such scaling will be easier if already separate

Comment: @AdamCopley, it's more of a guideline than a best practice. it really depends on the platform you are running MySQL on, in Linux RAM is over committed by the kernel, that means if you have 1 GB of RAM and you dedicate that entire 1 GB to MySQL it will work but it will doing a lot of disk I/O to swap memory in and out (paging). You'd have to check with others with different environments but I believe you'll find your best performance from a linux box. I have servers with 96 GB of RAM and allocate 64 GBs to the innodb_buffer_pool and the rest to a mix of join buffers and other services.

Comment: The 75% (or 80 or 70, depending on who you read) works OK for 4GB and above.  Below that, there is too much taken up by other things that you dare not use that high a percentage.  As for "over committing" (alias "swapping"), that is _terrible_ for MySQL because the code assumes, for example, that the entire buffer_pool is in RAM, and casually jumps around in it.  If 'pages' of it are 'swapped' out, performance _really_ suffers.

Comment: Please see (http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/129693/how-can-i-further-improve-my-table-and-queries)  for results!